# Browserslist error when starting dev server

Tags: npm, nuxt.js

After clone repository and installing dependencies i run dev server of nuxt and got errors of browserslist in postcss dependency. I've searched by keyword "android all" in node_modules folder but got nothing.

I've tried to remove package-lock.json and node_modules folder and reinstall all dependencies but got the same result

When starting the dev server i've got following error log

```
Unknown browser query android all. Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made typo in query.          12:00:56

  at unknownQuery (node_modules/postcss-preset-env/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:204:10)
  at node_modules/postcss-preset-env/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:296:11
  at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
  at resolve (node_modules/postcss-preset-env/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:237:18)
  at browserslist (node_modules/postcss-preset-env/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:361:16)
  at supportedBrowsers.some.supportedBrowser (node_modules/postcss-preset-env/index.js:438:105)
  at Array.some (<anonymous>)
  at stagedFeatures.filter.feature (node_modules/postcss-preset-env/index.js:438:80)
  at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
  at postcss$1.plugin.opts (node_modules/postcss-preset-env/index.js:438:44)
  at creator (node_modules/postcss/lib/postcss.js:133:35)
  at config.plugins.sortPlugins.map (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:4128:18)
  at Array.map (<anonymous>)
  at PostcssConfig.loadPlugins (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:4122:10)
  at PostcssConfig.config (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:4158:14)
  at StyleLoader.postcss (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:4215:39)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an issue with browserlist.
Try to update your dependencies.
Browserlist 4.6.3 is the latest and this problem was fixed it it.